# Edit epigraph locally

Tags: epigraphs

I am writing a book with several epigraphs, and I would like to change the configurations (like width, rule length, etc) of some of the epigraphs. Since I am only editing some of the epigraphs, I would like a way to keep the others with the default configurations.

**So, my question is:** is there a way to change the configurations of one - and only one - epigraph, keeping the rest of the epigraphs as they originally were?

If there is a way of changing the configurations inside the text, such that the new values get to be respected from the moment they are set on, I can just set the values as I want, write the epigraph and then reset them to be the default values again. In such case, I ask you: do you know what are the default values of epigraphs configurations (like width and rule length)? Where can I find them?

**Edit:**

As requested (sorry for the lack of information :/), here goes a code that expresses what I am talking about:

```
...
\usepackage{epigraph}
...
\epigraph{text1}{author1} % Epigraph with default configurations
...
% Make some changes, that either act only on the next epigraph, or can be unmade after it
\epigraph{text2}{author2} % Epigraph with new configurations
% Unmake the changes, if that's the case
...
\epigraph{text3}{author3} % Epigraph with default configurations
...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "epigraph"?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @TobiBS.

Comment: By "epigraph" I mean exactly what the dictionary defines, @Mensch, and I am planning to implement them through the `epigraph` package.

Comment: It must have been something to do with timing that this question was closed. I gave an answer while it was still open. The OP edited his question to include code remarkably similar to that in my answer. When was the question closed --- before my answer, before the OP's edits, or after all of these?

Comment: @Peter, I think the timeline was _you answered_ -> _I edited_ -> _question got closed_.

But it may have got closed while I was editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting on my very flaky mind-readers hat perhaps you are using the `epigraph` package. If so then you can locally change the epigraph layout.

```
...
\usepackage{epigraph}
...
\epigraph{text}{source}  % first epigraph
...
% \begin  % wrong for local redefinitions
\begingroup % local redefinitions
  \setlength{epigraphwidth}{0.7\textwidth} % make it wider
  % other changes
  \epigraph{text2}{source2}  % second epigraph
 % \end   % wrong for forget local redefinitions
\endgroup % forget local redefinitions
...
\epigraph{text3}{source3}  % third epigraph typeset as per first epigraph
...
```

For details of the default epigraph layout read the manual (`texdoc epigraph`) and in particular the first few lines of the code.

If you are not using the `epigraph` package then I have wasted my time due to the lack of information you provided. --- GOM

**EDIT**

In the above I used `\begin` and `\end` which was completely wrong as these take an argument. I should have used `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` instead.

Comment: Really cool, @Peter! I suppose that this usage of `\begin` and `\end` works for any kind of configurations, right?

Comment: I only tried to apply your suggestion now (this is so embarrassing...) and it didn't  work. I can't just type `\begin` and/or `\end`. LaTex complains with a "_invalid environment command_" warning.

Comment: Any idea on whether there is a way of defining a "`new_epigraph`" environment (as being the usual epigraph, only with the new configurations), so that I can use either of the epigraphs whenever I want?

Comment: @Valentino My apologies, I have no idea why `\begin` `\end` did not work for you. I tried them with the `article` class but they didn't work (according to Leslie Lamport they should have). Replacing `\begin ... \end` with `{...}` worked. My error, it should have been `\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{...}`. You can always define a new `epigraph` environment to suit your needs based on my original code --- just give your code a different name.

Comment: I've got a solution. `epigraph` _is_ an isolated environment. So we can put any change we want to make locally inside `{}` in `\epigraph{}`. For example, if we want to change the rule's length (the _rule_ is the line that appears between the phrase and the author), we can write `\epigraph{\setlength{\epigraphrule}{length} phrase}{author}`.

Comment: @Valentino To my embarrassment I've now discovered why `\begin` and `\end` don't work (see the edit to my answer). Should use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` instead.

Comment: Ok, that seems to work. It would be nice if you cited my solution as well in your answer. That way people get to know both options.

Comment: @Valentino Why don't you provide your solution as an answer instead of a comment? My revised answer is generally applicable to both environments and non-environment text.

Comment: I can't post an answer; the question is closed.